# Help decoding this Json ABI

Tags: abi

I'm interested in reading how dHedge implemented their asset-buying program so would greatly appreciate if you guys could help me decode their json abi. I couldn't find a json abi decoder anywhere as the github web3 library says it hasn't implemented json abi decoding yet.

Any help is appreciated

Edit: I forgot to include the link

https://docs.dhedge.org/dhedge-protocol/contract-details

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to read the smart contract code, you can retrieve it through etherescan:

https://etherscan.io/address/0x03D20ef9bdc19736F5e8Baf92D02C8661a5941F7#code

There you have the code and the write & read functions in case you want to interact with it.

Comment: Those are just a bunch of libraries that they used. And most of them are just the Open Zeppelin implementation. They don't show how they actually used any of them.

Comment: @Aidsbaby24 If you click in the proxy function it will point out to the latest factory contract at 0x14de5cd46c776d6b20579dd8c3de599ed7669362.